# Linear algebra determinant-area relation question

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an exercise where I am transforming a unit circle into an ellipse by some transformation $A$. Is it true that after the transformation the ellipse will have an area $\pi\cdot\mathrm{det}(A)$? I'm asking because during lectures we only talked about this rule applying to a unit hypercube in $n$ dimensions.

Comment: Yes, it will be original area (pi in this case for the unit circle)) * det(A)

Comment: Thank you! Could you give a proof or a link to a proof showing it for a generic shape in n (n=2 would be perfect) dimensions?

Comment: I suppose we could think of a general area as a double integral of the area element dxdy in Cartesian coordinates. This area element would transform to det(A)dxdy so that the new area would be det(A) times the original area integral.

Comment: The proof for a "generic" shape in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is to cover it by very small squares whose total area is very close to the area of the shape and then apply $A$ to each of the squares.  But there are exotic shapes ("non-measurable sets") for which this process gives inconsistent answers and one must develop an elaborate theory to understand what's going on; this is closely tied to change of variables in integration and is probably outside the scope of your linear algebra course.

Comment: the small square argument is understable though, as this is obvious for a square being stretched in x and y by some factors.

Answer (score 1):

Determinant is precisely the factor by which volume (area in 2-dimensions) change under the transformation. The new area is the norm of the transformed bivector $\| Av_1\wedge Av_2\|=\vert\det A\vert\cdot \| v_1\wedge v_2\|$. See also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Transformation_on_alternating_multilinear_n-forms). In order to find the area of a more complex surface partition it into infinitesimal parallelograms, the constant $\det A$ factors out. Similarly, in differential geometry we would be considering, e.g., the $dx\wedge dy$ volume form and the Jacobian determinant.